# Svg contida em DIV não segue "max-height: 100%"

Tags: css, layout-responsivo, svg

[Vejam o exemplo da estrutura primeiro.](http://jsfiddle.net/3bnv9a2y/1/)

```css
.follow-window-size-container {
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: green;
}

container-of-svg {
    max-height: 100%;
}

container-of-svg svg {
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="follow-window-size-container">
    <div class="container-of-svg">
        <img src="http://imgh.us/EU_food_contact_material_symbol.svg" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Meu objetivo é que a imagem em SVG (junto com seu container) se comprima e siga a mesma altura do `follow-window-size-container` (que segue a altura da window).

O certo seria funcionar desse jeito, acredito eu, já que o `max-height` força o elemento a não ultrapassar determinada altura. Estranhamente não estou conseguindo usa-lo agora...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O height do .container-svg precisa ser 100%, coloquei display:block na img só pra garantir. Dá uma checada no fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/3bnv9a2y/2/